# How to crawl multiple pages of a website?

Tags: web-scraping, web-crawler

I want to scrap a certain website of the type "http://www.mywebsite.com/search?name=jack&page=1". My query is how to I write the spider to crawl all the pages associated with "name=jack".

Comment: You're the second person I saw today to say `my query` instead of question... :\

Comment: it would be helpful to know what language you are writing in?